# My Hangman game created using PyQt5 and Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, hangman, pyqt

This is my Hangman game that I created using PyQt5 and Python 3.5 on my Windows 7 machine. What do you think? Is there anything you thing I could change/improve in terms of code or visually (font, font size, font color, image size, button size)?

([Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgcHx.jpg))

```
from sys import (exit, argv)
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QRegExp)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QToolTip, QPushButton, QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QIcon, QPixmap, QFont, QRegExpValidator)
from random import choice
from time import sleep

WORDS = ['Captivity', 'America', 'Europe', 'Federal', 'Gluten', 'Ridiculous', 'Automatic', 'Television', 'Difficult', 'Severe', 'Interesting', 'Indonesia', 'Industrial',
     'Automotive', 'President', 'Terrestrial', 'Academic', 'Comedic', 'Comical', 'Genuine', 'Suitcase', 'Vietnam', 'Achievement', 'Careless', 'Monarchy', 'Monetary', 
     'Quarantine', 'Supernatural', 'Illuminate', 'Optimal', 'Application', 'Scientist', 'Software', 'Hardware', 'Program', 'Colonial', 'Algorithm', 'Intelligent', 
     'Electricity', 'Verification', 'Broadband', 'Quality', 'Validation', 'Online', 'Telephone', 'Dictionary', 'Keyboard', 'China', 'London', 'Jamaica', 'Biology', 
     'Chemistry', 'History', 'Historian', 'Africa', 'Mathematics', 'Computer', 'Literature', 'Gravity', 'Guitar', 'Violin', 'Illuminate', 'England', 'China', 'Japan',
     'Canada', 'Suitcase', 'Wireless', 'Internet']

HANGMAN_PARMS = 100, 200, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation

class hangman(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.background = QLabel(self)
        self.background.setPixmap(QPixmap('background.jpg').scaled(201, 352, Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation))
        self.background.move(-1, -1)

        self.number = 1
        self.image = QLabel(self)
        self.image.setPixmap(QPixmap('hangman_{}.png'.format(self.number)).scaled(*HANGMAN_PARMS))
        self.image.move(60, 0.5)

        self.word = choice(WORDS)
        blank_word = '_ ' * len(self.word)
        blank_word.rstrip()  

        self.blank_word_label = QLabel(blank_word, self)
        font1 = self.blank_word_label.font()
        font1.setPointSize(14)
        self.blank_word_label.setFont(font1)
        self.blank_word_label.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.blank_word_label.setToolTip('Attempt to fill in the blanks')
        self.blank_word_label.move(0,200)
        self.blank_word_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.guessed_letters = ''

        self.btn = QPushButton('Check', self)
        self.btn.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 20))
        self.btn.setToolTip('Click to check if the entered letter is in the word')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.check_letter)
        self.btn.resize(102, 43)
        self.btn.move(99, 228)

        self.entered_letter = QLineEdit(self)
        regex = QRegExp("[a-z-A-Z_]+")
        validator = QRegExpValidator(regex)
        self.entered_letter.setValidator(validator)
        font2 = self.entered_letter.font()
        font2.setPointSize(24)
        self.entered_letter.setFont(font2)
        self.entered_letter.setMaxLength(1)
        self.entered_letter.setToolTip('Enter a letter and check if it is in the word')
        self.entered_letter.setFocus(True)
        self.entered_letter.returnPressed.connect(self.check_letter)
        self.entered_letter.resize(100, 43)
        self.entered_letter.move(0.5, 228)

        self.correct_or_incorrect = QLabel(self)
        self.correct_or_incorrect.move(1, 232)
        self.correct_or_incorrect.setVisible(False)

        self.you_lose = QLabel(self)
        self.you_lose.setPixmap(QPixmap('game_over.jpg').scaled(200, 160, Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation))
        self.you_lose.move(0.5, 0.5)
        self.you_lose.setVisible(False)

        self.you_win = QLabel(self)
        self.you_win.setPixmap(QPixmap('congratulations.jpg').scaled(200, 160, Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation))
        self.you_win.move(0.5, 0.5)
        self.you_win.setVisible(False)

        self.correct_word = QLabel('The word was:', self)
        font1 = self.correct_word.font()
        font1.setPointSize(14)
        self.correct_word.setFont(font1)
        self.correct_word.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.correct_word.move(0,170)
        self.correct_word.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.correct_word.setVisible(False)

        self.replay_btn = QPushButton('Play Again', self)
        self.replay_btn.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 15))
        self.replay_btn.setToolTip('Click to play another game of Hangman')
        self.replay_btn.clicked.connect(self.replay)
        self.replay_btn.resize(202, 33)
        self.replay_btn.move(-1, 239.8)
        self.replay_btn.setVisible(False)

        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 10))
        self.setGeometry(1390, 30, 200, 270)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.setWindowTitle('Hangman')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))      
        self.show()

    def check_letter(self):

            if self.entered_letter.text().lower() in self.word.lower():
                self.guessed_letters += self.entered_letter.text().lower()
                self.correct_or_incorrect.setPixmap(QPixmap('correct.png').scaled(40, 40, Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation))
                self.correct_or_incorrect.setVisible(True)
                QApplication.processEvents()
                sleep(0.1)
                self.correct_or_incorrect.setVisible(False)
                QApplication.processEvents()

            else:
                self.number += 1
                self.image.setPixmap(QPixmap('hangman_{}.png'.format(self.number)).scaled(*HANGMAN_PARMS))
                self.correct_or_incorrect.setPixmap(QPixmap('incorrect.png').scaled(40, 40, Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation))
                self.correct_or_incorrect.setVisible(True)
                QApplication.processEvents()
                sleep(0.1)
                self.correct_or_incorrect.setVisible(False)
                QApplication.processEvents()

            blank_word = ''
            for i in self.word:
                if i.lower() in self.guessed_letters:
                    blank_word += i   

                else:
                    blank_word += '_ '

            blank_word.rstrip()

            self.blank_word_label.setText(blank_word)
            self.entered_letter.setText('')
            self.entered_letter.setFocus(True)

            if self.number == 7:
                self.blank_word_label.setText(self.word)
                self.image.setVisible(False)
                self.entered_letter.setVisible(False)
                self.btn.setVisible(False)
                self.you_lose.setVisible(True)
                self.correct_word.setVisible(True)
                self.replay_btn.setVisible(True)

            if blank_word == self.word:
                self.image.setVisible(False)
                self.entered_letter.setVisible(False)
                self.btn.setVisible(False)
                self.you_win.setVisible(True)
                self.correct_word.setVisible(True)
                self.replay_btn.setVisible(True)

    def replay(self):
        self.number = 1
        self.image.setPixmap(QPixmap('hangman_{}.png'.format(self.number)).scaled(*HANGMAN_PARMS))
        self.word = choice(WORDS)
        blank_word = '_ ' * len(self.word)
        blank_word.rstrip()
        self.blank_word_label.setText(blank_word)
        self.guessed_letters = ''
        self.you_lose.setVisible(False)
        self.you_win.setVisible(False)
        self.correct_word.setVisible(False)
        self.replay_btn.setVisible(False)
        self.image.setVisible(True)
        self.entered_letter.setVisible(True)
        self.btn.setVisible(True)
        self.entered_letter.setFocus(True)                  



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(argv)
    ex = hangman()
    ex.show()
    exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `blank_word.rstrip()` does nothing, as `.rstrip()` does not modify the original string. You could do `blank_word = blank_word.rstrip()`, or simply put the `.rstrip()` on the line above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to point out some minor things about your style.
Following [PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) makes code easier to read :)

Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.

Imports should be grouped in the following order:

1. standard library imports
2. related third party imports
3. local application/library specific imports

So your imports would be:

```
from sys import exit, argv
from random import choice
from time import sleep

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRegExp
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QToolTip, QPushButton, QApplication, QWidget, 
QLabel, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap, QFont, QRegExpValidator
```

You should also add a few docstrings.
You can check for other minor mistakes with this tool: http://pep8online.com/

Comment: I personally also order imports alphabetically most of the time within each of the categories you listed in 1, 2, 3

Answer (score 3):

Very nice, there are no many things to improve.

I guess that this part of your code

```
WORDS = ['Captivity', 'America', 'Europe', 'Federal', 'Gluten', 'Ridiculous', 'Automatic', 'Television', 'Difficult', 'Severe', 'Interesting', 'Indonesia', 'Industrial',
     'Automotive', 'President', 'Terrestrial', 'Academic', 'Comedic', 'Comical', 'Genuine', 'Suitcase', 'Vietnam', 'Achievement', 'Careless', 'Monarchy', 'Monetary', 
     'Quarantine', 'Supernatural', 'Illuminate', 'Optimal', 'Application', 'Scientist', 'Software', 'Hardware', 'Program', 'Colonial', 'Algorithm', 'Intelligent', 
     'Electricity', 'Verification', 'Broadband', 'Quality', 'Validation', 'Online', 'Telephone', 'Dictionary', 'Keyboard', 'China', 'London', 'Jamaica', 'Biology', 
     'Chemistry', 'History', 'Historian', 'Africa', 'Mathematics', 'Computer', 'Literature', 'Gravity', 'Guitar', 'Violin', 'Illuminate', 'England', 'China', 'Japan',
     'Canada', 'Suitcase', 'Wireless', 'Internet']
```

was much time-consuming for typing many of apostrophes and commas - the faster approach is

```
WORDS = ("Captivity   America     Europe      Federal      Gluten      Ridiculous "
         "Automatic   Television  Difficult   Severe       Interesting Indonesia "
         "Industrial  Automotive  President   Terrestrial  Academic    Comedic "
         "Comical     Genuine     Suitcase    Vietnam      Achievement Careless "
         "Monarchy    Monetary    Quarantine  Supernatural Illuminate  Optimal "
         "Application Scientist   Software    Hardware     Program     Colonial "
         "Algorithm   Intelligent Electricity Verification Broadband   Quality "
         "Validation  Online      Telephone   Dictionary   Keyboard    China "
         "London      Jamaica     Biology     Chemistry    History     Historian "
         "Africa      Mathematics Computer    Literature   Gravity     Guitar "
         "Violin      Illuminate  England     China        Japan       Canada "
         "Suitcase    Wireless    Internet "
         ).split()
```

Note that it is one very long literal string written part by part (an closed in parentheses for avoiding `\` at the ends of the lines).

Comment: Or put them in a separate file entirely. CSV or DB, etc.

Comment: Why not use one triple-quoted string spanning multiple lines?

Answer (score 2):

It looks good, but I'm not a Qt expert.

I would have used model/view separation: the game code would be in one file and the UI code would be in a logically completely separated file.  For example, from the same game code you can write a pure text interface, or a Qt interface.

Also I would put the word list in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't much like `HANGMAN_PARMS` as a tuple. Why not separate variables or a dictionary? That way their meanings would be more explicit.

I don't see the point in `initUI` - why isn't that code in `__init__`.